# Обновление exim на Centos 6

Tags: exim, centos6

Недавно в новостях увидел предупреждение о найденной уязвимости в exim версии 4.91 и ниже, позволяющая получить доступ к root. В связи с чем решил обновиться командой:

`yum update exim`

Однако обновление произошло только до версии 4.91-1 . Не могу нигде найти информацию о том, как обновить до 4.92 . Есть ли способ обновиться прямо сейчас?

Answer (score 0):

Пока что только в тестовой ветке:

```
yum --enablerepo=epel-testing update exim
```

Comment: Не хочет даже через `-enablerepo=epel-testing`.